# rotating vector round origin using a scaler

Tags: javascript, vector, rotation, 2d

i understand that for rotation x = xcos(theta) - ysin(theta) and y = xsin(theta) + ycos(theta) so i wrote the folling code to do that however it fails (wrong result) and i carnt fingure out why.

```
rotate(pScaler) {
    this.xResult = (this.getX() * Math.cos(this.pScaler)) - (this.getY() * Math.sin(this.pScaler));
    this.yResult = (this.getX() * Math.sin(this.pScaler)) + (this.getY() * Math.cos(this.pScaler));
    return new Vector(this.xResult, this.yResult, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just double checked and relise i had copy and pasted the code that was working i was accedently looking at the wrong verion of the code ops.